# Possible to join on documents in separate MarkLogic databases?

Tags: marklogic

In MarkLogic 5.x is it possible to join documents in one database to documents in another database?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you mean doing a single search and merging search results from multiple databases.

You could try, and you could get some reasonable results probably, depending on the precise requirements, but it is not a recommended approach. It is like searching two separate Oracle databases. You'd have to do two separate searches, and merge results yourself, with all kinds of complications.

Better approach would be to just put the content in one database, and logically separate them using directories or collections. You can spread content accross multiple machines using a MarkLogic cluster, but that requires an Enterprise license..

HTH!

Comment: I'm trying to replicate what both Oracle and SQL Server allow, something like this: <p> `select au_fname from server1.pubs.dbo.authors

UNION ALL

select au_fname from server2.pubs.dbo.authors`

Comment: @todd I believe server1 and server2 in your example refer to database schemas, which live inside one oracle instance, or perhaps one oracle cluster. You can compare them with MarkLogic Databases. You can, as said, run queries across multiple database (using xdmp:eval or xdmp:invoke with a database option), and use XQuery code to join the results in any way you like. But stuff like pagination which is rather trivial usually, becomes quite complicated. In MarkLogic you wouldn't join in your code at all, but rely on clustering to take care of this under the hood..